# Know if you are dropping messages from a subscriber queue?

Tags: ros, messages, queue

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Is there a way to know when or how many messages are being dropped from a subscriber queue?

I'm mostly interested in occasionally reporting that node foo has dropped N packets since execution began.

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/11004/know-if-you-are-dropping-messages-from-a-subscriber-queue?/) by [Chad Rockey](https://answers.ros.org/users/29/chad-rockey/) on ROS Answers with karma: 4541 on 2011-08-24

Post score: 3

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

For messages that have a header field, I would think you could check that `header.seq` increments by only 1 for each message received. This is assuming all the messages are coming from a single publisher--there might also be some other wrinkles that don't spring immediately to mind.

---

Originally posted by [Patrick Bouffard](https://answers.ros.org/users/12/patrick-bouffard/) with karma: 2264 on 2011-08-24

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 0

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [Chad Rockey](https://answers.ros.org/users/29/chad-rockey/) on 2011-08-24**:
Actually, I was wondering if I had to use the header sequence for exactly this reason.  I was avoiding putting the header in since the rest of the information isn't useful.  I suppose you could always just add and set your own seq integer if you didn't want to use the full header.

**Comment by [bkx](https://answers.ros.org/users/1731/bkx/) on 2012-03-28**:
Checking the header field could work if you have only one publisher, but breaks down if more than one node is publishing messages on a topic.